# Como deletar todos os Cookies de uma página com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Há uma maneira de excluir todos os cookies (já existentes) relacionados a uma página, utilizando apenas JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

Seguem duas respostas retiradas [do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/).

Esta:

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

E esta:

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
 var c = document.cookie.split("; ");
 for (i in c) 
  document.cookie =/^[^=]+/.exec(c[i])[0]+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";    
}
```

As duas tem uma limitação parecida: elas não apagam cookies sem o "=", ou seja, cookies que tem um nome mas não tem um valor. Como isto é um caso raro, ambas vão funcionar bem em praticamente qualquer situação normal.

Para casos onde os *paths* sejam variados, tem esta outra resposta, mais "agressiva", mas que deve ser usada em conjunto com um loop como o das respostas acima para obter o nome de cada cookie:

```
function eraseCookieFromAllPaths(name) {
    // This function will attempt to remove a cookie from all paths.
    var pathBits = location.pathname.split('/');
    var pathCurrent = ' path=';

    // do a simple pathless delete first.
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

    for (var i = 0; i < pathBits.length; i++) {
        pathCurrent += ((pathCurrent.substr(-1) != '/') ? '/' : '') + pathBits[i];
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;' + pathCurrent + ';';
    }
}
```

Nota: como bem lembrado pelo @PapaCharlie, o *browser* não informa ao JS o path dos cookies, e a rotina acima para compensar esta limitação, faz uma varredura de "força bruta" nos possíveis paths para os *cookies* para tentar apagá-los seja lá em que profundidade estiverem. Isto só funcionará se o JS for chamado de um subnível igual ou maior que o setado no *cookie*. Uma possível expansão da idéia seria testar também o domínio com e sem o prefixo www.

Comment: Até onde sei, navegadores não informam o *path* nem *domain* dos cookies, e *location.pathname* só retorna o caminho do URL atual, no caso não vai substituir um cookie com *path=/*.

Comment: @PapaCharlie o loop na rotina tenta todos os niveis do path onde voce se encontra, por tentativa e erro. Antes do loop ele tenta setar o path "limpo", depois vai tentando pelas separações por barra, nivel a nivel até o atual.

Comment: Reparei agora, boa sugestão. Se o AP não usar subdomínio, você pode incluir outro *for* para *www.dominio.com, e .dominio.com*, asism assegura a varredura pelo *domain*.

Comment: @PapaCharlie os autores dos códigos estão nas respostas da pergunta linkada, do SOzão. Sacada boa dos autores, eu apenas transcrevi as que me pareciam mais sensatas ;) - Essa do com e sem www é realmente uma boa idéia. Editei com uma menção a sua observação, depois vou rever melhor o código.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que o código abaixo resolva.

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
var expire = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{
    cookie = cookies[i].split("=")[0];
    expire.setDate(expire.getDate()-1);
    document.cookie = "asd=; expires=" + expire;
}
```

---

Mas há algumas considerações sobre `domain, path e httponly`.

1. Se o cookie for definido como `httponly = true`, não será possível remover via javascript. O parâmetro *httponly* serve justamente para evitar a manipulação dos cookier pelo JS, adicionando segurança.
2. Se você criou um cookie com os parâmetros `domain e path`, terá de usá-los para a remoção usando a linha abaixo substituindo no código acima.

`document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + expire + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=" + path;`